# Replace/Delete text between 2 javascript comments with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace/delete any text (also with line breaks) that is between 2 javascript comments, but the forward-slashes make me headache.

What I have at the moment, but is not working:

```
var text="//beginTESTTESTTEST//end";
var regex = "/\//begin+(.)+\//end*/g";
console.log(text.replace(regex,""));
```

Expected output would be
"//begin//end"

Thank you

Comment: The expected output is that the comments are still there, but the text in between replaced/deleted.

Comment: May be: `str.replace(/(\/{2}begin)[^]*?(\/{2}end\b)/g, '$1$2');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

- Do not put the regex literal inside a string literal (i.e. do not use single/double quotes or backticks around the `/regex_pattern/`), it ruins the regex as the slashes become part of the pattern
- `(.)+` makes little sense as the capturing group is placed around a `.` that matches any char but line break chars, and effectively, you capture the last char from the matched sequence. BUT: **we capture what we need to keep, and we just match what we want to discard.** Thus, put the `(...)` only around those parts you want to keeep, `//begin` and `//end` and use *backreferences* in the replacement part to restore these substrings in the result
- `*` is greedy, and in case there are more than one match in the string, `.*` will overmatch across several delimiters, so it is safer to use a lazy version, `.*?`
- `.` does not match line break chars, so it is better to use `[^]` (only in ECMAScript regex flavor), `[\s\S]` / `[\d\D]` / `[\w\W]`, or use `.` with `s` flag (in the contemporary ECMAScript 2018+ compliant JS environments)
- Mind that inside a regex literal, `/` are "special" and need escaping with `\`.

So, here are a couple of possible fixes:

```js
var text="//beginTESTTESTTEST//end";
// Capture the parts you need to keep and use backreferences in the replacement
console.log(text.replace(/(\/\/begin)[\w\W]*?(\/\/end)/g, "$1$2"));
// Just match the pattern and use a literal in the replacement
console.log(text.replace(/\/\/begin[\w\W]*?\/\/end/g, "//begin//end"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Lookahead and Lookbehind :

```
text.replace(/(?<=\/\/begin)(.*)((?=\/\/end))/gm,'');
```

Comment: It did not work for me @navid ... Thanks anyway